# Why there is no output for wrapped IO in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
main :: IO (IO ())
main = (pure (print)) <*> (pure "Hello World!") *>
       (pure (print)) <*> (pure "I am Haskell.") *>
       (pure (print)) <*> (pure "Let's start our journey.")
```

I wrote a Haskell program as mentioned above. I compiled and run it. But there is no output for this program. Why?.

I have no idea to solve this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`IO (IO ())` is the type of an effectful program producing (but not running) another effectful program. Hence your code does not print anything.

Compare with this imperative, JavaScript-like pseudo code.

```js
function foo() {
   return function() {
      print("hello");
   };
}

foo(); // Why doesn't this print anything?
```

In the last line, we build a function, but we never call it, hence the `print` is never executed.

In Haskell, `return`ing an IO action does not run it, much like in the code above returning a closure does not invoke it.

Another Haskell example:

```
foo :: IO (IO ())
foo = do
   putStrLn "a"            -- this action is run
   return (putStrLn "c")   -- this action is returned without being run

main :: IO ()
main = do
   action <- foo   -- here only "a" is printed
   putStrLn "b"    -- "b" is printed
   action          -- "c" is printed
```

Finally, `main` is a bit special in Haskell, in that it can have type `IO a` for whatever type `a` we want, but the value of type `a` will be discarded as if we actually run

```
realMain :: IO ()
realMain = main >> return ()
```

IMHO, using anything but `main :: IO ()` is confusing. I'd rather add something like `>> return ()` at the end of the code than to specify a weird pointless return type.

Comment: It look like a halting problem?

Comment: @MinThutaShein I don't think the halting problem is truly relevant here.

Comment: " The *> operator is similar to >>, and it discards the result of the action on the left and returns the result of the action on the right. Both >> and *> are used for sequencing actions in a monadic context, like the IO monad. " Here is i found the actual solution. Your answer is useful for me. Thanks!

Comment: main = m >>= (\x -> x) . I extracted the wrapped IO () like this and only the last line was shown. >> and *> discards the result of the action on the left.

Comment: @MinThutaShein Note that `action >>= (\x -> x)` can also be written as `join action`, using the library function [`join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a `](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) which can "flatten" the nested `IO` (or any other monad).

Comment: I had previously thought `main` *had* to have type `IO ()`. For those interested, it's Chapter 5 of the Haskell Report that defines `main` as an `IO` action of arbitrary type, with execution discarding the resulting value.

Comment: Not sure how the author arrived at `IO (IO ())` type but I occasionally create functions with this type by accident, wondering why nothing is done. Explicit type signatures help to prevent this bug. :)